# UWP: Cannot access LicenseInformation

Tags: javascript, windows, winapi, windows-store-apps, uwp

I am using the following piece of code to check in my UWP-JS app if an in-app purchase is active:

```
(function () {
    // Initialization
    // var store_app = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp;
    var store_app = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator;
    var licenseInformation = store_app.licenseInformation;

    // Check for Product
    if (licenseInformation.productLicenses["product1"].isActive) {
        // do something
    } else {};
})();
```

when I debug this I get the following error for line 5:

> 0x803d0000 - JavaScript runtime error: The input data was not in the expected format or did not have the expected value.

I am following this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-in-app-product-purchases)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are copying the C# sample code but failing to translate it to JS. In JS, properties are camelCase. `if (licenseInformation.productLicenses["product1"].isActive)`. For more details see the [Windows Store JS sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/win10-1507/Samples/Store/js/js/scenario2-inAppPurchase.js#L44).

Comment: Another possibility is that your XML has an incorrect ExpirationDate. It should be in the form `<ExpirationDate>2016-01-01T00:00:00.00Z</ExpirationDate>`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you for your hint! That does not fix the error though. Where should I specify that expiration date?

Comment: Since you are using `CurrentAppSimulator`, the information comes from the XML files you pass to `reloadSimulatorAsync`.

Comment: Or there could be some other error in your XML.

Comment: @RaymondChen Do you mean `WindowsStoreProxy.xml`? I don't have a `<ExpirationDate>` tag in there ...

Comment: @RaymondChen Ah, thank you for the hint. Seems like Atom messed that file up. I just deleted it and VS created a new one automatically. Works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Atom Editor messed the [`WindowsStoreProxy.xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials-using-the-windows-applicationmodel-store-namespace#proxy) file up.
I just deleted it and Visual Studio created a new file.